# C++ file writing/reading

Tags: c++, arrays, file, input, output

I'm trying to create an array, write array to the file and than display it. It seems to be working but i get just part of the output (first 3 elements) or i get values over boundaries.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
      int arr[20];
      int i;

      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
            cout << "Enter the value to the array: " << endl;
            cin >> arr[i];
      }
      ofstream fl("numbers.txt");

      if (!fl)
      {
            cout << "file could not be open for writing ! " <<endl;

      }
      for (i = 0; i < arr[i]; i++)
      {
            fl<<arr[i]<<endl;
      }
      fl.close();
      ifstream file("numbers.txt");
      if(!file)
      {
            cout << "Error reading from file ! " << endl;
      }
      while (!file.eof())
      {
             std::string inp;
             getline(file,inp);
             cout << inp << endl;
      }
      file.close();
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks wrong: `for(i=0;i<arr[i];i++)`

Comment: The `while (!file.eof())` is also not correct. The while loop should be testing on the `getline()` result, but you likely won't notice the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its like hmjd said

```
for(i=0;i<arr[i];i++)
```

looks wrong

it should look like this

```
int size;
size=sizeof(your array);

for(i=0;i<size;i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

The terminating condition in the `for` loop is incorrect:

```
for(i=0;i<arr[i];i++)
```

If the user enters the following 5 `int`s:

> 1 0 4 5 6

the `for` loop will terminate at the second `int`, the `0`, as `1 < 0` (which is what `i<arr[i]` would equate to) is `false`. The code has the potential to access beyond the bounds of the array, for input:

> 10 11 12 13 14

the `for` loop will iterate beyond the first 5 elements and start processing unitialised values in the array `arr` as it has not been initialised:

```
int arr[20];
```

which could result in out of bounds access on the array if the elements in `arr` happen to always be greater than `i`.

A simple fix:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
```

Other points:

- always check the result of I/O operations to ensure variables contain valid values:

  ```
  if (!(cin >> arr[i]))
  {
      // Failed to read an int.
      break;
  }
  ```

the `for` loop must store the number of `int`s read into the `arr`, so the remainder of the code only processes values provided by the user. An alternative to using an array, with a fixed size, and a variable to indicate the number of populated elements is to use a [`std::vector<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) that would contain only valid `int`s (and can be queried for its `size()` or iterated using iterators).

- `while (!file.eof())` is not correct as the end of file flag will set only once a read attempted to read beyond the end of the file. Check the result of I/O operations immediately:

  ```
  while (std::getline(file, inp))
  {
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//for(i=0;i<arr[i];i++)
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
```

[EDITED]
I would initialize the array with 0 like this: int arr[20] = {0}; In this case you can use for example:

```
while ((arr[i] != 0 || i < sizeof(arr))
```

Comment: :) thanks a lot for your quick answer. And what id i dont know how many  items are stored in aray? and why is i<arr[i] wrong? i was thinking about i<arr[i]-1 but its not working either. Thanks

Comment: I would initialize the array with 0 like this: int arr[20] = {0}; In this case you can use while arr[i] != 0 for example.

Comment: "why is i<arr[i] wrong?" In what way is it possibly right? What you think it means? "And what id i dont know how many items are stored in aray?" -- You put them there so you must have a way to know how many there are.

Comment: sizeof(arr) returns the size of the array not the number of elements - use sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)

Answer (score -1):

```
i<array[i]
```

It is wrong beacuse it comapres with the content of the array ,it does not check the size of array .